# magento search autocomplete not working in desktop view but working fine in mobile layout

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch, autocomplete

Here is the URL:

http://digitalupstarts.com/hof/

Open this URL in desktop and mobile, and type "marco" in the search bar. You will find that in desktop the autosuggest is not working, and in mobile autosuggest is working fine.

Here is the full code of `form.min.phtml`:

```
<form id="search_mini_form" action="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getResultUrl() ?>" method="get">

<!--- Categories dropdown for Search -->

<?php /*$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') */?><!--
<?php /*$_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() */?>
<?php /*$currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') */?>
<?php /*if (count($_categories) > 0): */?>
    <select id="category" class="myinput-text required-entry widthinput" name="category">
            <?php /*foreach($_categories as $_category): */?>
                <option value="<?php /*echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) */?>"><?php /*echo $_category->getName() */?></option>
                    <?php /*$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) */?>
                    <?php /*$_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() */?>
                    <?php /*if (count($_subcategories) > 0): */?>
                            <?php /*foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): */?>
                                 <option value="<?php /*echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) */?>"><?php /*echo '|--'.$_subcategory->getName() */?></option>
                            <?php /*endforeach; */?>
                    <?php /*endif; */?>
            <?php /*endforeach; */?>
        </select>
    --><?php /*endif; */?>
    <!--- End : Categories dropdown for Search -->


    <div class="form-search">

        <div class="search-content">

           <!-- <label for="search"><?php //echo $this->__('Search:') ?></label>-->
            <input id="search" type="text" name="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getQueryParamName() ?>" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Search Here...') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Search Here...':this.value;" value="Search Here..." class="input-text" maxlength="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getMaxQueryLength();?>" />
            <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Search') ?>" class="button"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
            <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
                var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', '<?php echo $this->__('Search...') ?>');
                searchForm.initAutocomplete('<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getSuggestUrl() ?>', 'search_autocomplete');
            //]]>
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: which extension you are using or any custom theme?

Comment: Extension name is "magento-autocomplete-master"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Picture:
[image]

Have you changed somthing? I think script work only for the first search.
I think in this case it doesn`t matter that is hidden.
I hope this will help you something.

Answer (score 0):

maybe in the desktop view the JS is missing.
I found it in the mobile template but not in the desktop view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://digitalupstarts.com/hof//js/magebuzz/searchautocomplete/ajaxsearch.js"></script>
```

Is the autocomplete/autocomplete.phtml in the template folder?

Comment: thank you so much for your reply but its not working. please help me out. client will kill me

Comment: Can you look in your form.mini.phtml? Maybe post the content? I think there is something missing. Or you can compare the code from the mobile and the desktop template. Have you a sandbox to test?

Comment: can i have your contact number please?

Comment: And there is no such folder called  "autocomplete" in whole directory.

Comment: sorry I can not give you telephone support. Have you found your form.mini.phtml in the main template?

Comment: yes  i have  found form.min.phtml . but i have no idea what to do with form.min.phtm
please guide me

Comment: have you found any solution..i am stuck

Comment: I need more information. Can you paste the form.mini.phtml content here?

Comment: In the folder defoult/your theme/template is there a folder called catalogsearch?

Comment: In my folder I have 2 files: form.mini.phtml and the second should be result.phtml

Comment: i have already add form.min.phtml code in answer

Comment: Please check and let me please know

Comment: So the file is OK. But I found something. Have you change something in the template? Like place the search in an other way? There is an hidden search (via CSS). The autosearch for this works. You can try it if you change the css in your browser to "block". Then you see waht I mean.